# AWS EMR: How to migrate data from one EMR to another EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I currently have an AWS EMR cluster running with HBase. And I am saving the data to S3. I want to migrate the data to a new EMR cluster on the same account. What is the proper way to migrate data from one EMR to another?
Thank you

Comment: If you are saving data to S3 then what data do you want to migrate?

Comment: I want to use a HA (High Availability) HBase cluster instead of normal HBase in my current EMR cluster. I need to create a new EMR-HBase cluster for that

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways two copy the table from one cluster to another:

1. Use [CopyTable](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#copy.table) utility. The disadvantage is that it can degrade the region server performance or there is a need to disable the tables prior to copy.
2. [Hbase Snapshots.](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#ops.snapshots) (Recommended). It has a little impact on region server performance.

You can follow the [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-snapshot.html) to perform snapshot/restore operations.
Basically you will do the following:

1. Create Snapshot
2. Export to S3
3. Import from S3
4. Restore to Hbase